# ASP.NET - Redis Session State Provider - Session_End

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redis

I'm using [RedisSessionStateProvider](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider/) within ASP.NET MVC application.

Everything works fine except that `Session_End` event never gets called.

```
protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Do stuff whenever a session ends
}
```

Here's my web.config:

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="RedisSessionProvider" timeout="1">
  <providers>
    <add name="RedisSessionProvider" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" host="localhost:6379"
      accessKey="" ssl="false"/>
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Versions:

- Windows 10 Pro
- ASP.NET MVC 5.2.2
- Redis 2.8.2104 64-bit
- Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider 1.6.5

**What's the proper way to implement custom logic whenever a session ends using RedisSessionStateProvider?**

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?